# Varchar(65k) vs TEXT vs DB rows for Subscriptions

Tags: mysql, scaling, subscription

what is the best approach to handle subscriptions on a large scale, let's say each user can have up to 500 subscriptions.

1.VARCHAR(65K) - we store the 'ids' inside a string separated by commas, then we use LOCATE('asset_id') to find out if the user is subscribed or not.

2.TEXT - the same, we hold all the 'ids' the user is subscribed to inside a long string separated by commas, but we use 'LIKE' to find the substring instead of LOCATE.

3.DB Rows - each user will occupy 500 rows in the table, so 1 million users are 500m rows...

what is the best approach? did I miss any other approach?

Comment: A flat file? You'll get the same (lack of) features than packing everything into a single database cell at a fraction of the cost.

Comment: they say it's bad to store large strings in varchar because it can't be stored in memory and it will cause a high disk operation, so it's not recommended to use varchar(3000) or more.

Comment: 3 every time...

Comment: whats wrong with adding all subscription_id's to 1 long string of 65kb, it can hold up to 5000 ids. and then using LOCATE or LIKE.  instead of 5000 rows it takes only 1 row in the table